# How to list all remote names without branches on git?

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to script a generic prune command that prunes branches from all remotes configed on the repository instead of doing it for a specific remote (usually origin).

If you have a single remote like origin, the output should be just origin

In order to do this I need a command that would list all remotes. The closes thing I came upon was:

```
git branch -av | sed -n 's/remotes\/\([^\/]*\).*/\1/p' | uniq
```

Is there another less complex way to retrieve the list of remotes?

At this moment the pruning looks ugly:

```
git branch -av | sed -n 's/remotes\/\([^\/]*\).*/\1/p' | uniq | xargs git remote prune --dry-run
```

Comment: `git remote`, with no additional arguments, lists all remotes.

Comment: @torek you should add it as answer!